# How to loop the maze

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm a beginner with python. I couldn't figure out how to start new game in my maze.
I have tried various options but they all end whe with errors. What should I do? Thank you in advance.

I have tried destroy the frame_top where maze is located then create another maze with function new_game. But this function calls errors:

```
import tkinter as tk
import random
from tkinter import messagebox

global SIZE
global ROW
global COLUMN
SIZE = 10
COLUMN = 7
ROW = 7

departure = [[1, 1]]    
playerX = 1
playerY = 1
beforeX = 1
beforeY = 1

maze = []
for y in range(ROW) :
    sub = []
    for x in range(COLUMN) :
        if y==0 or y==ROW-1 or x==0 or x==COLUMN-1 :
            sub.append("WALL")
        else :
            sub.append("FIELD")
    maze.append(sub)

def dig(x, y) :
    maze[y][x] = "PATH"
    canMove = []
    if maze[y-1][x]=="FIELD" and maze[y-2][x]=="FIELD" :
        canMove.append("UP")
    if maze[y+1][x]=="FIELD" and maze[y+2][x]=="FIELD" :
        canMove.append("DOWN")
    if maze[y][x-1]=="FIELD" and maze[y][x-2]=="FIELD" :
        canMove.append("LEFT")
    if maze[y][x+1]=="FIELD" and maze[y][x+2]=="FIELD" :
        canMove.append("RIGHT")
    if len(canMove)==0 :
        return
    
    direction = random.choice(canMove)
    if direction=="UP" :
        maze[y-1][x]="PATH"
        maze[y-2][x]="PATH"
        y -= 2
    if direction=="DOWN" :
        maze[y+1][x]="PATH"
        maze[y+2][x]="PATH"
        y += 2
    if direction=="LEFT" :
        maze[y][x-1]="PATH"
        maze[y][x-2]="PATH"
        x -= 2
    if direction=="RIGHT" :
        maze[y][x+1]="PATH"
        maze[y][x+2]="PATH"
        x += 2
    departure.append([x, y])    
    dig(x, y)
##    print(departure)
##    print(dig(x, y))


def keyPress(event) :
    global playerX,playerY,beforeX,beforeY
    if event.keysym=="Up" and maze[playerY-1][playerX]=="PATH" :
        beforeX = playerX
        beforeY = playerY
        playerY -=1
    if event.keysym=="Down" and maze[playerY+1][playerX]=="PATH" :
        beforeX = playerX
        beforeY = playerY
        playerY +=1
    if event.keysym=="Left" and maze[playerY][playerX-1]=="PATH" :
        beforeX = playerX
        beforeY = playerY
        playerX -=1
    if event.keysym=="Right" and maze[playerY][playerX+1]=="PATH" :
        beforeX = playerX
        beforeY = playerY
        playerX +=1

def move() :
    can.create_oval(beforeX*SIZE+1, beforeY*SIZE+1, (beforeX+1)*SIZE-1, (beforeY+1)*SIZE-1, fill="white", width=0)
    can.create_oval(playerX*SIZE+2, playerY*SIZE+2, (playerX+1)*SIZE-2, (playerY+1)*SIZE-2, fill="blue")
    if playerX==COLUMN-2 and playerY==ROW-2 :
        messagebox.showinfo("INFORMATION", "CONGRATULATIONS!!!")
        frame_top.destroy()
##        for widget in frame_top.winfo_children():
##           widget.destroy()
        new_game()
    can.after(100, move)    

    
def new_game():
    
    departure = [[1, 1]]    
    playerX = 1
    playerY = 1
    beforeX = 1
    beforeY = 1
    maze = []
    canMove = []
    print (maze)
    for y in range(ROW) :
        sub = []
        for x in range(COLUMN) :
            if y==0 or y==ROW-1 or x==0 or x==COLUMN-1 :
                sub.append("WALL")
            else :
                sub.append("FIELD")
        maze.append(sub)
    while len(departure)!=0 :   
        start = departure.pop(0)
        x = start[0]
        y = start[1]
        dig(x, y)
        print(x)
        print(y)
        
    for y in range(ROW):        
        for x in range(COLUMN):
            if maze[y][x]=="PATH" :
                color = "white"
            else :
                color = "black"
            can.create_rectangle(x*SIZE, y*SIZE, (x+1)*SIZE, (y+1)*SIZE, fill=color, width=0)
    
    can.create_rectangle((COLUMN-2)*SIZE, (ROW-2)*SIZE, (COLUMN-1)*SIZE, (ROW-1)*SIZE ,fill="red")
        
    move()
    



global win
win = tk.Tk()
frame_top = tk.Frame(win)
frame_top.pack()

global can
can = tk.Canvas(frame_top, width=COLUMN*SIZE, height=ROW*SIZE)
can.pack()
m = tk.Menu(win)
win.config(menu=m)
fm = tk.Menu(m, tearoff=0)

om = tk.Menu(m, tearoff=0)
m.add_cascade(label='Options', menu=om)
om.add_command(label='New Game',command= new_game )

om.add_command(label='Settings', )

while len(departure)!=0 :   
    start = departure.pop(0)
    x = start[0]
    y = start[1]
    dig(x, y)
    print(x)
    print(y)

for y in range(ROW):        
    for x in range(COLUMN):
        if maze[y][x]=="PATH" :
            color = "white"
        else :
            color = "black"
        can.create_rectangle(x*SIZE, y*SIZE, (x+1)*SIZE, (y+1)*SIZE, fill=color, width=0)

can.create_rectangle((COLUMN-2)*SIZE, (ROW-2)*SIZE, (COLUMN-1)*SIZE, (ROW-1)*SIZE ,fill="red")  

move()      
win.bind("<Any-KeyPress>", keyPress)    

win.mainloop()

main()
```

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", 
line 839, in callit
    func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/fileend.py", 
line 92, in move
    new_game()
  File "C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/fileend.py", line 128, in new_game
    can.create_rectangle(x*SIZE, y*SIZE, (x+1)*SIZE, (y+1)*SIZE, fill=color, width=0)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2835, in create_rectangle
    return self._create('rectangle', args, kw)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2805, in _create
    return self.tk.getint(self.tk.call(
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!frame.!canvas"
```

Comment: That error means you're trying to create a rectangle on a canvas that has been destroyed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use two different ways to create a new game. So it's differ from each other and you do not understand what you make wrong.One them main flow and other one is new_game method. I just merged them.

Second thing is you destroy your frame and your canvas inside it. So you also destroyed your canvas this is why yo get errors. Instead can.delete("all") going to clear all items inside.

You have keypress(event) function yo do not need to update tens of times every second your move(). Just if you get any press, simple update it by calling move function.

Other thing is, when you are moving inside maze, instead of moving your player you are creating a new blue dot and repaint your old dot. It's bad habit you should avoid it. If it would be too much movement inside your maze, that mess would cause to slow down.

Lastly, in your new_game method you need to use global keyword otherwise your declerations only creates local variables.

This is full solution. It correctly starts new games and contains all improvements mentioned above.

```
import tkinter as tk
import random
from tkinter import messagebox

SIZE = 10
COLUMN = 7
ROW = 7

departure = [[1, 1]]    
playerX = 1
playerY = 1
beforeX = 1
beforeY = 1

maze = []
player = None
for y in range(ROW) :
    sub = []
    for x in range(COLUMN) :
        if y==0 or y==ROW-1 or x==0 or x==COLUMN-1 :
            sub.append("WALL")
        else :
            sub.append("FIELD")
    maze.append(sub)

def dig(x, y) :
    maze[y][x] = "PATH"
    canMove = []
    if maze[y-1][x]=="FIELD" and maze[y-2][x]=="FIELD" :
        canMove.append("UP")
    if maze[y+1][x]=="FIELD" and maze[y+2][x]=="FIELD" :
        canMove.append("DOWN")
    if maze[y][x-1]=="FIELD" and maze[y][x-2]=="FIELD" :
        canMove.append("LEFT")
    if maze[y][x+1]=="FIELD" and maze[y][x+2]=="FIELD" :
        canMove.append("RIGHT")
    if len(canMove)==0 :
        return
    
    direction = random.choice(canMove)
    if direction=="UP" :
        maze[y-1][x]="PATH"
        maze[y-2][x]="PATH"
        y -= 2
    if direction=="DOWN" :
        maze[y+1][x]="PATH"
        maze[y+2][x]="PATH"
        y += 2
    if direction=="LEFT" :
        maze[y][x-1]="PATH"
        maze[y][x-2]="PATH"
        x -= 2
    if direction=="RIGHT" :
        maze[y][x+1]="PATH"
        maze[y][x+2]="PATH"
        x += 2
    departure.append([x, y])    
    dig(x, y) 


def keyPress(event) :
    global playerX,playerY,beforeX,beforeY
    if event.keysym=="Up" and maze[playerY-1][playerX]=="PATH" :
        beforeX = playerX
        beforeY = playerY
        playerY -=1
    if event.keysym=="Down" and maze[playerY+1][playerX]=="PATH" :
        beforeX = playerX
        beforeY = playerY
        playerY +=1
    if event.keysym=="Left" and maze[playerY][playerX-1]=="PATH" :
        beforeX = playerX
        beforeY = playerY
        playerX -=1
    if event.keysym=="Right" and maze[playerY][playerX+1]=="PATH" :
        beforeX = playerX
        beforeY = playerY
        playerX +=1
    move()

def move() :
    can.moveto(player,playerX*SIZE+1, playerY*SIZE+1)
    print(playerX,playerY)
    if playerX==COLUMN-2 and playerY==ROW-2 :
        messagebox.showinfo("INFORMATION", "CONGRATULATIONS!!!")
        can.delete("all")
##        for widget in frame_top.winfo_children():
##           widget.destroy()
        new_game()

    
def new_game():
    global player,playerX,playerY,beforeX,beforeY,departure,maze
    departure = [[1, 1]]    
    playerX = 1
    playerY = 1
    beforeX = 1
    beforeY = 1
    maze = []
    canMove = []
    print (maze)
    for y in range(ROW) :
        sub = []
        for x in range(COLUMN) :
            if y==0 or y==ROW-1 or x==0 or x==COLUMN-1 :
                sub.append("WALL")
            else :
                sub.append("FIELD")
        maze.append(sub)
    while len(departure)!=0 :   
        start = departure.pop(0)
        x = start[0]
        y = start[1]
        dig(x, y)
        print(x)
        print(y)

    for y in range(ROW):        
        for x in range(COLUMN):
            if maze[y][x]=="PATH" :
                color = "white"
            else :
                color = "black"
            can.create_rectangle(x*SIZE, y*SIZE, (x+1)*SIZE, (y+1)*SIZE, fill=color, width=0)

    can.create_rectangle((COLUMN-2)*SIZE, (ROW-2)*SIZE, (COLUMN-1)*SIZE, (ROW-1)*SIZE ,fill="red")  
    
    player = can.create_oval(playerX*SIZE+2, playerY*SIZE+2, (playerX+1)*SIZE-2, (playerY+1)*SIZE-2, fill="blue")
    can.tag_raise(player)
    



global win
win = tk.Tk()
frame_top = tk.Frame(win)
frame_top.pack()

global can
can = tk.Canvas(frame_top, width=COLUMN*SIZE, height=ROW*SIZE)
can.pack()



m = tk.Menu(win)
win.config(menu=m)
fm = tk.Menu(m, tearoff=0)

om = tk.Menu(m, tearoff=0)
m.add_cascade(label='Options', menu=om)
om.add_command(label='New Game',command= new_game )

om.add_command(label='Settings', )


new_game()


win.bind("<Any-KeyPress>", keyPress)    

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you for all your hard work. I would wish see your answer earlier. I  have solved  this problem by my own recently  by harder way, but not as beautiful as your.